# Date format in AtTask

Tags: attask

When viewing things like the task list, the date format does not honour regional settings in some browsers on some platforms. Is there a way to have the date format support regional settings? It seems it defaults to the peculiar US month/day/year format, which is extremely annoying and confusing.

Surely the default should be something that is unambiguous and in a format that is common to most people?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the browser you use will determine how the dates are formatted.
While IE/Safari uses the computers language settings
In chrome and Firefox it will use the language configured in setup section under language.
Chrome > preferences > Language and input settings
Firefox > Preferences > Content Tab > Languages

If it is set to english it will use MM/DD/YYYY if you select english (UK) it will use DD/MM/YYYY

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: *Is there a way to have the date format support regional settings?*. In Safari or Firefox,  AtTask doesn't use either the computer or regional settings in AtTask preferences. I would expect it to support d/m/y unless English (US) was chosen.